# Alternative for celery on Windows for long running task on remote host

Tags: python, redis, rabbitmq, celery, message-queue

I have issues while running long running task which takes around 2 and half hours to complete. The issue is either I get socket timeout error or the task result keeps on waiting forever.

So any other message queue framework which is suited for this scenario which will support running tasks on remote (different IP address) windows machine and return the result computed from remote machine.